# nested countable local basis for a point x

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Given $B_x = \{B_1, B_2, \ldots\}$, a local basis at $x$. Show that we can construct $D(x) = \{B_1^*, B_2^*, \ldots\}$, a local basis at $x$, such that $B_1^* \supseteq B_2^* \supseteq \ldots$, is a nested local basis at $x.

Here is my attempt:

I define the elements of $D(x)$ as

$B_j^*= \bigcap_{i=1}^{j} B_{i} \subset B_{j} \subset U$

Note that since $D(x) \subset B(x)$ and $B(x)$ is enumerable, then $D(x)$ is countable. Also, note that for all $U$ neighborhood of $x$, there exists $B^* \subset D(x)$ such that $B^* \subset U$.

Now, if I consider a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and as $B(x)$ is a local countable basis, there exists $B_{k} \in B(x)$ such that $B_{k} \subset U$. But note that as $B_k^* = \bigcap_{i=1}^{k} B_{i} \subset B_{k}$, this implies that $B_k^* \subset U$. Therefore, $D(x)$ is a local countable basis of $x$. is this correct?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: But what's the question? You seem to have already found a solution

Comment: @FShrike I want to know if its correct

Comment: Then use the tag "solution-verification". And trust yourself!